# SSHで接続しようとすると connection refused と表示される

Tags: linux, ssh

iTerm にて `ssh root@192.0.2.1` と入力すると以下のメッセージが表示されます。
本来ならパスワードを求められるはずなのですが、どのようにすればいいのでしょうか？

```
ssh: connect to host 192.0.2.1 port 22: connection refused
```

Comment: いろんな原因が考えられるのでもう少し情報を追記すると回答が得られやすいかもしれません。ssh のデバックモード (-vvv) オプションをつけた場合のデバッグ情報、SSHサーバ側のログファイルのメッセージを質問に追記できますか？

Answer (score 14, accepted):

connection refused とは、パスワード等での認証以前に、接続先の sshd に接続することができなかったということを意味します。具体的には、

- IPアドレス（この場合 `192.0.2.1`）が間違っていて、別のPCを指している
- 接続先で sshd が起動していない
- 接続に使うポートが間違っている
- ファイアウォールによって通信が遮断されている

などの原因が考えられます。

Comment: connection refusedは、TCP SYN に対して TCP RST が返ってきた場合ですから、「接続先のコンピュータが起動していない」は除外してよいのではないかと思います。宛先のコンピュータがいない場合 (と、ファイアウォールでパケットが捨てられた場合) は no route to host のようなエラーになると思います。

Comment: @yoh2 ありがとうございます、回答を修正しました。タイムアウトになったりもしますね。

Answer (score 2):

一度pingもしくは、tracerouteコマンドで試されてはどうでしょうか？

pingは普通linuxにインストールされていますが、tracerouteは個別にインストールする必要があります。

pingは通信先のコンピュータに通信可能（ちゃんと動いている）かどうか調べる方法で、
tracerouteは、自分のip addressからどのルートを経由し、目的ip addressまで行っているのかを調べる方法です。この方法ですと、どこで行き詰っているのかを調べることができます。
どちらの方法でも、ちゃんと目的ip addressまで届いていれば、通信は帰ってきますよ。

pingのコマンドは、

```
ping 192.0.2.1
```

Tracerouteのコマンドは、

```
//yum, rpmなど別の方法でもtracerouteはインストールできますが、
//何のためapt-getだけでもインストールの仕方を書いておきます。
sudo apt-get install inetutils-traceroute
traceroute 192.0.2.1
```

です。

一度詰まってしまうと、イラッとしてしまいますが、頑張ってください。

Comment: pingを試してみたところ、通っていることがわかりました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 2):

ポートが間違っていました。
`ssh -p 指定したポート番号 root@192.0.2.1`
とすることでログインできました。皆さんありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

root以外でやれば入れませんか？
ほぼ他の人の指摘通りですが、もう一つ、

- rootで直接sshログインするのは禁止するように設定されている

可能性があるように思います。root以外のユーザーでやれば入れるのではないでしょうか。

Comment: その場合は connection refused ではなく、パスワード入力の後に Permission denied と表示されるのではないでしょうか。