# CentOS8 で dnf update 実行後に再起動を行うと ssh 接続ができなくなった

Tags: centos

GMOクラウドのVPSを使用していますが。

```
dnf update
```

を実行後に再起動を行いSSHでの接続を行おうとすると、

```
ssh: connect to host [ IP アドレス ] port [ Port番号 ]: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

となります。

アップデートを行った後になにかしなくてはならないのでしょうか？

<環境について>
・GMO Cloud VPS
・CentOS8

何か必要な情報などございましたら、お知らせくださいませ。

metropolis様より頂いた件が下記となります。
ssh -vvv host です
（再インストールをし「dnf update」をしていない状態です）

```
OpenSSH_8.0p1, OpenSSL 1.1.1c FIPS  28 May 2019
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host [ host ] originally [ host ]
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: not matched 'final'
debug2: match not found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1 (parse only)
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]
debug1: configuration requests final Match pass
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname [ host ] is address
debug1: re-parsing configuration
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 51: Including file /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf depth 0
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf
debug2: checking match for 'final all' host [ host ] originally [ host ]
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 3: matched 'final'
debug2: match found
debug3: /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/05-redhat.conf line 5: Including file /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config depth 1
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/crypto-policies/back-ends/openssh.config
debug3: gss kex names ok: [gss-gex-sha1-,gss-group14-sha1-]
debug3: kex names ok: [curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1]
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to [ host ] [[ host ]] port 22.
debug1: connect to address [ host ] port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host [ host ] port 22: Connection refused
```

Comment: 再起動前にはssh接続ができていたのですよね。再起動後、しばらく時間をおいて実行しても現象が発生しますか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。今やってみましたが、同じでした。

Comment: まずは対象のマシンが現在起動しているのかを確認してみてください。アップデートのトラブルで繋がらないのか、再起動のつもりでシャットダウンしてしまったのか等、原因を切り分ける必要があります。 / ssh で繋がらなくても、VPS ならコンソール環境が用意されているはずです。 https://vps.gmocloud.com/service/vpsportal.html

Comment: `ssh -vvv host` の結果を追記してみて下さい。

Comment: VPSコンソールにて、状態の確認を行いましたが表面上起動状態となっております。
また、GMOクラウドのコンソールは、うまく起動されませんでした。

Comment: 参考: [SSHで接続しようとすると connection refused と表示される](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/15118/)

Comment: 「Resource temporarily unavailable」から「Connection refused」に現象が変わったのですか？現象が異なりますが、私の環境(CentOS8)でdnf updateをかけたところCentOS8が立ち上がらなくなり、原因を調査中です。

Answer (score 0):

2021年1月に、質問された方の環境(GMO Cloud VPS)で発生した問題と同様(※)の問題が私の環境で発生していましたが、2021/07/18現在、私の環境ではこの問題が発生しなくなりました。
　　　※ dnf update 後に、CentOS8が立ち上がらなくなる
　ホストのWindowsのバージョン、VirualBox、カーネルのバージョンが変わっており、何が理由で問題が発生しなくなったのかは不明のままですが、私としてはカーネルのバージョン4.18.0-240.el8.x86_64が直接原因だったのではないかと考えています。

【確認に使用した環境】

(1)  ホスト　Win10 Pro 1909
　　↓
(2)  ホスト　Win10 Pro 20H2

(1)  VirualBox  バージョン 6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.6.2)
　　↓
(2)  VirualBox  バージョン 6.1.22 r144080 (Qt5.6.2)

(1)  カーネル　4.18.0-240.el8.x86_64
　　↓
(2)  カーネル
　　　　　　　4.18.0-257.el8.x86_64 ※ dnf update前
　　　　　　　4.18.0-315.el8.x86_64 ※ dnf update後

(1)問題が発生たときのバージョン
　　(2)今回確認したバージョン

CentOSをインスト―ルしたときのメディア CentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-20201211-dvd1.iso

---

#### 【対処方針】

私の環境で発生した現象とは違うかもしれませんが、4.18.0-193のカーネルで起動することができれば問題が解消するかもしれません。
※　GMOクラウドのVPSで、どうすればよいか分かりません

#### 【問題の現象】

私の環境(VirtualBox)で`dnf update`でCENTOS8が立ち上がらなくなりました。
※再現性があります。
VMを起動すると画面が真っ暗のまま先にすすみません。

VBox.logをみると以下のエラーが出ています。

```
01:01:40.197365 MsrExit/0: 0010:ffffffffbc264d98/LM: WRMSR 00000033, 20000000:00000000 -> VERR_CPUM_RAISE_GP_0!
```

どのような意味を持つのか少しだけ調べてみましたがよくわかりませんでした。
Hyper-Vに関係ありそうな古い記事がありましたので、Hyper-Vは有効、無効を切り替えてみましたが、現象は変わりませんでした。
【追記】systeminfo.exeで確かめたところ、コントロールパネルでHyper-Vを無効化しても完全には無効になっていなかったです。Hyper-Vを完全に無効化できれば解決するかもしれません。

#### 【原因】※推測です

カーネルバージョンが4.18.0-193.el8.x86_64から4.18.0-240.el8.x86_64に変わったことが原因と考えています。

`dnf update`後のデフォルトのカーネル①ではVMが起動できません。②を選ぶとVMが起動できます。

①CentOS Linux (4.18.0-240.1.1.el8_3.x86_64) 8
②CentOS Linux (4.18.0-193.28.1.el8_2.x86_64) 8 (Core)

①は`dnf update`で作成されました。

【確認に使用した環境】

- ホストOS
  Win10 Pro 1909
- VirualBox
  バージョン 6.1.16 r140961 (Qt5.6.2)
- CentOSをインスト―ルしたときのiso
  CentOS-8.2.2004-x86_64-dvd1.iso

CentOS-8.3.2011-x86_64-dvd1.isoとCentOS-Stream-8-x86_64-20201211-dvd1.isoでインストールすると同じと思われる現象が発生します。
なおCentOS-8.2.2004-x86_64-dvd1.isoは現在入手不能なようです。※個人的なバックアップが残っていたため再現テストができました。

Comment: お忙しい中ありがとうございます。
確認してみます